# How to determine "timelike"-ness without using a coordinate system?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, causality

It has been stated [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/100719) that:

> we can say, without introducing a coordinate system, that the interval associated with two events is *timelike*, *lightlike*, or *spacelike*

.

This assertion appears at variance with

- the definition of "*time-like (or light-like, or space-like) intervals*" as defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_intervals explicitly in terms of "*differences of the space and time coordinates*", and
- the definition of "*curves*" as "*chronological (or timelike)*", "*null*" (or "lightlike"), or "*spacelike*", and thus correspondingly of pairs of "*points*" of any such "*curve*" as "*timelike (or lightlike, or spacelike)* related to each other" of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Curves which explicitly requires the notion of [Lorentzian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentzian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold) and thus according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Mathematical_definition uses coordinates as subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and their topological relations (as "*coordinate system*").

Therefore I'd like to know:
How can be determined whether the interval associated with two events (which are given or characterized and distinguished by naming, for either event, the distinct individual participants which had been coincident at that event) is for instance "*timelike*", **without** using any coordinates and coordinate system?

Is it correct that the interval associated with two events (given as described above) is "*timelike*" if and only if there exists at least one participant who took part in both of these events?

Comment: To take this down a level, how does one 'know' the timelike direction to assign the timelike coordinate to?  Clearly, the timelike direction does not depend on one's choice of coordinates!

Comment: Alfred Centauri: "_[...] Clearly, the timelike direction does not depend on one's choice of coordinates!_" -- Is that "_clear_ (to you)" e.g. just as the distinction between "before" and "after" was considered self-evident (and indeed more salient than pretty much any other notion) by [A.A.Robb](https://archive.org/details/theoryoftimespac00robbrich)? To me, that's fine as well; though I'd have to reconcile with Einstein's "All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences ...". Either way: coordinates/manifolds were **not** self-evident.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you mean by "the distinct individual participants which had been coincident at that event".  What participants?  What do you mean by "coincident"?  Are you talking about reference frames?

Comment: Muphrid: "_What participants?_" -- Those **who we consider routinely when discussing RT**: [elements of a railway embankment (e.g. "railway ties") $A$, $B$, $M$; elements of a train (e.g. its "ends", or "rows of seats inbetween") $A'$, $B'$, $M'$; etc.](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_I#Section_9_-_The_Relativity_of_Simultaneity). Elsewhere (see below) Einstein also called them "material points"; Minkowski wrote correspondingly of "substantial points"; MTW (Box 13.1) referred to "principal identifiable points". (contd.)

Comment: @Muphrid: Muphrid: "_What do you mean by "coincident"?_" -- What else but [what Einstein meant by: "_All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences {such as} encounters between two or more {... participants}_"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity#ch.3.p.776) (contd.)

Comment: @Muphrid: Muphrid: "_Are you talking about reference frames?_" -- Sure; in the sense of a (any) particular set of distinct participants such that there is no meeting/passing/coincident involving any two of them; a.k.a. [congruences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28general_relativity%29).

Answer (score 2):

How about this for a more "physical" definition: two points in space-time are time-like separated if and only if a massive particle starting at one could, if subjected to appropriate finite forces, reach the other.

Replace "massive" with "massless" to get the definition of light-like separation. If neither is possible the the points are space-like separated.

Comment: Nathaniel: Yes -- that's certainly the kind answer I had expected as motivation/justification for the quoted statement. My/The conclusion is: representing the notions "timelike", "lightlike", "spacelike" on the basis of coordinates/manifolds, such as [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Causal_relations) is **too narrow**. Instead, these notions are definable (or understood outright) without reference to coordinates/manifolds. "_massive_"; "_massless_" -- I wouldn't presume such notions outright, but define them as sketched in http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/37714

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ be functions on the reals to points (events) in spacetime.  Let these be "straight" curves, in the sense that $\lambda', \mu', \nu'$ each all have the same direction for all values of their parameters.  For example, $\lambda(u) = \lambda_0 + lu$ is a simple case, as $\lambda'(u) = l$.  The vector $l$ is the vector along the direction of the straight curve.

Given these three straight curves, we can define events $A$, $B$, $C$ that are the intersections of $\lambda, \mu$; $\lambda, \nu$; and $\mu, \nu$.  $A$ is point defined by the parameters $u, v$ such that $\lambda(u) = \mu(v)$.  If some material objects are following these worldlines, then the objects meet at these intersections, at these events.

The rest of the process of determining whether the interval between, for example, $A$ and $B$ is timelike, spacelike, or lightlike is then similar to Julio Parra's answer:  say we want to determine whether the interval between $A$ and $B$ is spacelike, timelike, or lightlike.  The common worldline between these two events is $\mu$.  We would then integrate the derivative to find the length of the spacetime interval between these two events along the worldline $\mu$:

$$s^2 = \int_{v_A}^{v_B} \eta[\mu'(v), \mu'(v)] \, dv$$

And the sign of $s^2$ then determines whether the interval is spacelike, timelike, or null (it depends on the metric).

I think the key point is the identification of some connecting straight worldline between two events--some "observer" or "participant" who takes part in both events of interest.  EDIT: no other connecting worldline will give the same answer, but the worldline that extremizes the answer is considered canonical for defining this quantity.  In the flat spacetime case, that's the straight path.

In general, we can talk about whether vectors are spacelike, timelike, or lightlike without considering two particular events.  These are properties of directions in spacetime, not necessarily pairs of events.

Comment: Muphrid: "_Let $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ be functions on the reals to points (events)_" -- Oh no!, **no coordinates, please!** But let's go on: "_in spacetime. [...] The vector $l$ is [...]_" -- This seems to presume that the set of events under consideration ("_spacetime_") were given as a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space or at least with (all) intervals already known even **quantitatively**. That's hardly "events being given (only) by naming participants", as required in my question. (contd.)

Comment: Muphrid: "_I think the key point is the identification of some connecting straight worldline between two events--some "observer" or "participant" who takes part in both events of interest._" -- There you go! (+1 on this item only.) Btw.: Why did you require "_straight worldlines_", instead only (more generally) "smooth" ones, or (even) "equal _sign_ for all intervals between pairs of elements of the _connecting_ arc"? "_[...] properties of directions in spacetime, not necessarily pairs of events._" -- In my question I took this detour via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Curves

Comment: @user12262 Regarding the straight curves $\lambda, \mu, \nu$: I have not chosen any coordinate system at that time. Yes, there is a presumption that we're in a Minkowskian vector space. That is the foundation of special relativity and allows us to talk about points and such without reference to any particular coordinate system. Are you particularly looking for an answer that make no reference to Minkowski vector space?

Comment: @user12262 Regarding your second point, I used straight curves here for simplicity because then $\mu'$ is constant and $s^2 = \eta(\mu', \mu') (\Delta v)^2$.  But as I said, "Any other connecting worldline should give the same answer; this is merely the simplest approach."

Comment: @Muphrid, it is my opinion that there is no reward engaging http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12262/user12262 .  Of course, your mileage may vary.  I've left my answer here only for the benefit of others and I do not intend to engage the OP further here.

Comment: @Muphrid: "_I have not chosen any coordinate system at that time._" -- How do you distinguish "_function on the reals to (some set of) events_" from "_coordinate system (of that set of events)_" ?? "_Minkowskian vector space. That is the foundation of SR_" -- Maybe of Minkowskian geometry. OTOH, concerning the (Einstein's) foundation of RT (incl. SRT) I repeat ["_All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences {...}_"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity#ch.3.p.776)

Comment: A coordinate system refers to a set of tuples that describe every point in space(time). The functions $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ do not describe every point in spacetime. If one had a coordinate system already, one would expect the coordinates of some event on the worldline $\lambda$ to be quite different from the parameter $s$ such that $\lambda(s)$ is that event.

Comment: @user12262: It sounds like you want someone to say, for example, a massive observer could follow a worldline connecting two timelike events, while a photon could follow a worldline connecting two lightlike events, and if neither is the case, then the interval between those events is spacelike. That's all well and good, but then you're just exchanging stuff you don't understand in math for stuff you don't understand about physics: e.g. how do we know which worldlines massive observers can follow?

Comment: Muphrid: "_A coordinate system refers to a set of tuples that describe every point in space(time). The functions $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ do not describe every point in spacetime._" -- But those (fewer) tuples which refer only to a (proper) subset of "_every point in space(time)_" are still called "coordinates", right? And one element of one such tuple is still called "a coordinate", isn't it? (And I didn't explicitly read in your answer, that $\lambda, \mu,$ or $\nu$ were **not** parametrizations of "_every point in space(time)_"; but perhaps you meant to imply that somehow ...) (contd.)

Comment: Muphrid: "_one would expect coordinates of some event on worldline $\lambda$ to be quite different from the parameter $s$ such that $\lambda (s)$  is that event._" -- Expectations concerning coordinates?? (How come? ...) "_which worldlines massive observers can follow?_" -- (+1 for excellent use of "_observer_" instead my feeble "participant" ;). Well: MTW (Box 13.1) presume "principal indentifiable" fellows. I asked this question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/97824/how-to-determine-the-order-of-indications-of-a-clock already to learn/discuss possible semblance to a "_line_" ...

Comment: @user12262: No, sorry, perhaps I was trying to be too sophisticated here.  $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ are just *worldlines*. I was trying to talk about events in spacetime as the intersections of worldlines. Now, you could argue that the parameterization of these lines is just as arbitrary as choosing coordinates. However, an "arclength" parameterization would still exist, and for a massive object, that would give the object's spacetime location as a function of the object's proper time.

Comment: Muphrid: "_[...] an "arclength" parameterization would still exist_" -- For some suitable definition of how to measure _"arclength"_; indeed: surely **there exists** one. Now: (1) would such admitted existence help in answering my question; i.e. in deciding whether the particular "_arc_" (or "curve", or just "interval" or "pair of events") under consideration were "timelike", or not? And (2): does e.g. "counting ticks", in some particular given case, provide a parametrization that is "affine to _arclength"_? Or not? Most importantly: How to find out?

Answer (score 1):

One has not necessarily to know all this quantitative interval stuff to distinguish time-likeness. Suppose an observer lives on a body without (significant) atmosphere, such as our Moon. All events observed by means of light (EM radiation) belong to observer’s [light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) and hence are separated by a null interval from the observer. All events observed indirectly (either by reflected or scattered light, or by their material traces) belong to observer’s past cone and hence are separated by a **time-like** interval from the observer. Events separated by a space-like will not be seen in any way, as well as the entire future cone (with both null and time-like intervals). But the observer can influence events of the future cone, whereas events with space-like intervals are inaccessible *in any direction*, from observer’s present moment.

Suppose, we [pinged our lunar resident-observer](http://llcd.gsfc.nasa.gov/) (event P), he replied (event Q), and we received the reply (event R). Intervals P–Q and Q–R are null. Interval from anything on Earth before P and Q is time-like, with Q at the future end. Interval from Q and anything on Earth after R will also be time-like, with Q at the past end. Intervals from Q and our history between P and R are space-like: neither can our resident-observer at Q know anything about P⋯R (P excluded), nor can it influence anything in P⋯R (R excluded).

Ī answered the question with respect to the physical spacetime. If the question is about mathematical formalism to deal with spacetime without coordinates, then examples from the previous paragraph can be interpreted as a partial order relation.

Comment: Incnis Mrsi: "_[...] reflected or scattered light, or by their material traces_" -- So, applying this terminology to what I asked specificly at the end of my question text: Do you agree that two events ($\mathcal{P, Q}$) are related by a _timelike interval_ `1:` **if** there exists at least one "_material trace_" which took part in both of these events; Or `2:` **if** there exists at least one "_material trace_" who to part in distinct events $\mathcal{A, B, Q}$ (in that order) where $\mathcal{A, P}$ as well as $\mathcal{B, P}$ are _lightlike_; [... to be continued]

Comment: [... continued] Or `3:` **if** there exists at least one "_material trace_" who to part in distinct events $\mathcal{A, B, P}$ (in that order) where $\mathcal{A, Q}$ as well as $\mathcal{B, Q}$ are _lightlike_?

Comment: Strictly speaking, two endpoints of a time-like interval are not necessarily causally related *in fact*, but with respect to @user12262’s points: `1` – if we speak about massive bodies, then yes; `2` – light-likeness of A–P and B–P (future endpoints are P) doesn’t imply anything about P–Q; `3` – certainly no if *future* endpoints are Q. By the way, situations `2` and `3` are not possible in Special Relativity.

Comment: Incnis Mrsi:"_Strictly speaking, two endpoints of a time-like interval are not necessarily causally related_" -- Alright; [causal relations, as considered in geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Causal_relations) are not quite the same as [causation, e.g. due to some "material trace propagating"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causation). "_[...] situations `2` and `3` are not possible in Special Relativity._" -- But they certainly are (read the descriptions carefully again ...)

Comment: @user12262: in Minkowski’s world, if interval A–B is time-like, then:

    • future light cones of A and B never intersect;
    • past light cones of A and B do not intersect.
 It is, generally, not true in a curved spacetime.

Comment: Incnis Mrsi: "_in Minkowski’s world, if interval A–B is time-like, then: • future light cones of A and B never intersect; • past light cones of A and B do not intersect. _" -- Correct (where "_A_" and "_B_" denote distinct events). However: the future light cone of one of them (without loss of generality, say the future light cone of "_A_") and the past light cone of the other ("_B_") **do intersect**. (And, thereby, the past light cone of "_A_" and the future light cone of "_B_" do not intersect.) That's pretty much the point of my examples `2` and `3`.

Comment: Incnis Mrsi: "_It is, generally, not true in a curved spacetime._" -- Also correct. But would that invalidate my examples `2` and `3` ?

Comment: (Occasional) intersections and self-intersections of light cones in a curved spacetime show that relational formalism has some bugs there, and can’t substitute for differential geometry. But in Minkowski’s space partial order relations perform well.

Comment: Incnis Mrsi: "_relational formalism [...]_" -- I didn't know this technical term for what I'm trying to get at (and what I believe Einstein/Robb/EPS/Schelb/Schröter/... were trying to get at); so: thanks for pointing that out. "_has some bugs there_" -- Quite possibly. Can they be addressed/fixed systematically? "_and can’t substitute for differential geometry._" -- I'm not asking for substitution; but any comprehensible physical **foundation** in the first place ...

Comment: Incnis Mrsi: "_But in Minkowski’s space partial order relations perform well._" -- You may find my related, somewhat generalized question interesting: ["Which causal structures are absent from any nice patch of Minkowski space?" (PSE/q/66636)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/which-causal-structures-are-absent-from-any-nice-patch-of-minkowski-space) ...

Comment: @user12262: Ī mean http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Binary_relation of partial order (although, strictly speaking, Minkowski space needs a 3-valued binary relation (you said: *three possible assignments*), or two ordinary binary relations).

Yes, bugs of partial order relations in General Relativity can be fixed systematically with conformal Lorentzian geometry. Not long ago Ī investigated its implications for FLRW cosmology (unfortunately it isn’t published anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

[image]

From "[Gravitation and Spacetime](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107012945)" via Google Books

---

Added to address a comment below:

> *My question was intended to be addressed without referring to any coordinates; including no coordinates (!) such as "clock times T, T1,
>   T2" or somesuch.*

But these clock times **aren't** coordinates.  The reading of a single clock is the [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) along the worldine of the clock, i.e., *it is an invariant and coordinate independent measure of time*.  From the Wikipedia article "Proper Time":

> In relativity, **proper time is the elapsed time between two events as
>   measured by a clock that passes through both events**.

Moreover, in the 2nd paragraph of the text above we have:

> The radar-ranging procedure permits us to bypass the coordinate
>   system, **so we can measure the spacetime interval without the use of
>   coordinates.**

Consider a clock at rest with respect to you.  The 3 orthogonal spacelike directions are evident as is the (Lorentzian) orthogonal timelike direction.  The ticks of the clock gives a proper time *parameter* along the *timelike* worldline of the clock.

We can *define* the coordinate time, in the frame in which the clock is at rest, as the proper time given by the clock.  And, we can *define* space coordinates as described above.

In your comment, you put the cart before the horse.  The coordinates were *defined* by the direct measurement of the interval, not the other way around.

Comment: My question was intended to be addressed **without referring to any** coordinates; including no coordinates (!) such as "_clock times_ $T$, $T_1$, $T_2$" or somesuch. (But of course my question referred to the quoted statement by you, Alfred Centauri. So -- did you not mean your statement as strictly as I meant my question? ...) However, reading in your answer: "_[...] it emits a light signal [...] and it receives the echo_", apparently concerning some particular participant (one-and-the-same "_it_") -- does this not suffice to determine "timelike"-ness, without mentioning any coordinates?

Comment: @user12262, it is either clear or it isn't.  You've been, I believe, deliberately obtuse in the past and I believe that is the case now.  I have no further interest in this as I don't see any possible profit in it.

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, I have updated my answer to address the OP's comment above.

Comment: Alfred Centauri -- You should learn: (1) That a clock is not necessarily a good clock (cmp. MTW Fig. 1.9). (2) That, and How it is measured **whether** for some real-valued (or integer-valued) coordinate parametrization $T$ of given indications of a participant (e.g. in terms of "number of _ticks_") the **duration** (a.k.a. "prope time") of that participant from any one "_tick_" to "the next _tick_" was constant, or not (cmp. MTW Box 16.4). (3) How to determine “timelike”-ness without using a coordinate system (from answers of other users given here). Do you concede any of these points?